# Nuance SpeechKit Stopped Working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, speech-recognition

I'm using SpeechKit ( Free account ) for voice to text conversion in my app using Swift.
It was working perfectly fine but has stopped working suddenly on all the devices where I was testing. I've cross checked and the app key and id are correct. What is causing this.

Comment: Nick brother please guide.
Can I use a real device (not simulator) for testing SpeechKit with sandbox credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Their free account expires in 90 days. May be that’s the reason it’s not working anymore.
Please note that their free subscription is very limited if you want to distribute your app because of the following restrictions

(a) no more than one (1) concurrent connection;

(b) connections from no more than 3 unique devices per day;

(c) daily volume not to exceed 100 transactions per day; and

(d) a ninety (90) day term from your acceptance of this Agreement (the "Term");

Comment: Just check and my account has expired :(

Comment: please help.
would the sandbox credentials works properly on a real device (not simulator).?